# Do pre-written modules exist regarding the role the drow played in the Crown Wars?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms, lore, drow

I'm building a campaign that includes the [drow](http://neverwinter.wikia.com/wiki/Drow) and read about the [Crown Wars](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Crown_Wars) which has elements I'd like to include.  In addition to pulling ideas from these articles I would like to know if any pre-made modules exist that I could run my players through surrounding the Crown Wars?  This seems to be a largely untapped setting for adventures.

Comment: I'm happy to format the question in any manner that will simply get me an answer but I really am looking for pre-written resources that I can "steal ideas from" to flesh out my own campaign.  :)  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Since it is after the fourth crown war that the Ilythiiri elves become the drow, what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: I have updated my question.  I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

There are no modules set that far back.

Also, the Drow didn't exist until the end of the Fourth Crown War.

Looking through the wiki page you linked, you see repeated references to the Dark Elves.

If you have a look here at the [Dark Elf wiki page](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_elf), you can see that it says...

> Dark elves, were elves, known as Ssri-tel-quessir in the elven tongue, and were the ancestors of the drow.

Then if you look down at the Fourth Crown War, you see...

> The most powerful mages and clerics succeeded in completing the ritual in about -10,000 DR, though it had the adverse effect of corrupting all dark elves, not just the intended Ilythiirians. The dark elves were driven underground, and the epithet dhaerow would eventually change into drow.

Towards the end of the Fourth Crown War we get this little snippet (taken from the [Crown War Timeline](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Crown_Wars_timeline))

> The rise of the first drow civilizations in the Underdark beneath southern Faerûn and their constant harassment of the Vyshantaar forces over the next five centuries help prevent Aryvandaar annexing Keltormir or any other lands.

And that's all the information we have on drow. Their 'Dark Elf' ancestors took part in the first 4 Crown Wars, but the actual drow didn't exist until the latter part of the fourth...then they had only a tangential involvement in the remaining two, in that they kept annoying the Vyshantaar forces and preventing them from expanding.

All information on those pages is derived from the sourcebook: *Cormanthyr: Empire of the Elves*, and AD&D 2E sourcebook that is pretty much all we know about that era.

Answer (score 3):

The sourcebook *Cormanthyr: Empire of the Elves* (C:EotE) **used to be a free download** on the [website of Wizards of the Coast](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/downloads) (unfortunately the link is currently down, but perhaps you can do a little search on the web). It provides all the information that is posted on the FR wikia site you quoted, as well as some further details (about two double-column pages of information). There are also a couple of pages of rules modifications for holding elven campaigns in the ancient times.

This sourcebook is part of a set of products collectively known as the *Arcane Age*. The campaign settings in the set consisted of *C:EotE* and *Netheril: Empire of Magic* (which also used to be freely available for download). There were two published modules: *The Fall of Myth Drannor* and *How the Mighty Are Fallen*. **Both of these modules are way (about 10 thousand years) after the Crown Wars. Since TSR was going bankrupt at the time, nothing more came out in this line.**

And finally, as I mentioned in an early comment to your question, **the drow did not exist until after the Fourth Crown War** (circa -10,450DR). Quoting from the *C:EotE*:

> The final fate of Miyeritar so enraged the Ilythiiri that their battle-rage and sheer barbarism destroyed the realm of Shamel Othreier ... by fire within four decades of the Disaster. Their nonelven tactics, continued hostilities and aggressions, and their all-consuming hatred for all but their own race forced a swift and irrevocable decision from the ruling elves of Keltormir, Aryvandaar, and other enclaves: The Ilythiiri, or dhaeraow must be cast out of Corellons favor!
>
> -10,000: **Descent of the Drow**: Corellon's magic, as directed through his priests and High Mages, transforms the dark elves, whether the corrupt Ilythiiri or others, into the drow.